# How do i append query string from managed bean to url? JSF

Tags: jsf

Can this method work?

```
public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello.jsp?name=" + "laala";
}
```

I am unable to access, query string using the above method. I tried ${param.name} as well as request.getParameter("name"). They both return null. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either fire a [redirect](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29)..

```
public void sayHello(){
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.redirect("/Hello.jsp?name=" + "laala");
}
```

.. or if you're already on JSF2, then just define them in navigation case:

```
<to-view-id>/Hello.jsp?name=#{bean.property}</to-view-id>
```

<sub>(although the `.jsp` file extension less or more hints that you're not on JSF2 yet)</sub>

When using the JSF2 navigation case, if you want the new URL get reflected in the browser address bar, you need to add a `<redirect/>` entry, else it will just do a *forward*.

Comment: You may also use `<f:metadata><f:viewParam name="name" value="#{bean.property}"/></f:metadata>`

Comment: @John: this isn't exactly what the OP was asking.

Comment: That is true @BalusC but the result will be a query string which includes the view parameters as ../Hello.jsp?name=something

Answer (score 2):

maybe this would help you.
check out f:param with h:commandLink

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html